# Identification of non-latin characters by keydown

Tags: events, firefox, keydown, non-latin

There is a problem in some browsers, for example, Firefox.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).keydown(function(e){         // Or keyup or keypress
          alert(***look at output***);
     }
}
```

when typing non-latin characters as "<"-"б"-"Б" (russian) shows:

```
keydown    keyCode=0 which=0 charCode=0
keypress   keyCode=0 which=1073 charCode=1073 char=б
keyup      keyCode=0 which=0 charCode=0
```

the same character in Chrome shows:

```
keydown    keyCode=188 which=188 charCode=0
keypress   keyCode=1073 which=1073 charCode=1073 char=б
keyup      keyCode=188 which=188 charCode=0
```

**Problem:**
Identify keydown handler in all browsers, without using keypress (because of different charCodes on different keyboards layouts).

Comment: The charCode corresponds to the actual character being input.  The keyCode corresponds to which key was pressed, and differs on different OSes for the same physical key, as well as differing by keyboard layout for the same character.  So what exact problem are you trying to solve?  Are you really looking for a specific physical key, not a specific character?

Comment: keyCode is the same for "<","б","Б" in Chrome, IE and Safari, but charCode is different. Anyway, the problem is solved by adding async keypress listener for the firefox case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but with keypress. By listening keypress handle special for firefox bug, when with cyrillic keyboard layout doesn't work "<",">".

**Solution:** on pressing keyboard button we listen keydown and keypress handels at the same time. If the cyrillic character pressed firefox keyCode output is 0 and keydown ignore it. On the other hand, keypress takes keyCode == 0 and makes an output "<" or ">".